# Cannot load checkpoint file

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am running a python script on two tensorflow models. The script just read the checkpoint file and prints its content. I'm using this script to validate that the checkpoint file is valid.
The script:
https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/tools/inspect_checkpoint.py

Model 1 - facenet: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5MzpY9kBtDVSTgxX25ZQzNTMGc/view

model 2:  http://download.tensorflow.org/models/inception_v1_2016_08_28.tar.gz

on desktop Ubuntu 14.4, docker on Ubuntu 14.4, docker on OSX - it works perfect.
on ubuntu 16.4 on AWS and on docker on ubuntu 16.4 on AWS - it doesn't.

assuming the docker eliminates the os version, I afraid the error related to the fact that it runs on AWS.

the error:

```
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1014, in _do_run
target_list, options, run_metadata)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1034, in _do_call
raise type(e)(node_def, op, message)
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.DataLossError: Unable to open table file /data/model/a.ckpt: Data loss: not an sstable (bad magic number): perhaps your file is in a different file format and you need to use a different restore operator?
[[Node: save/restore_slice_318 = RestoreSlice[dt=DT_FLOAT, preferred_shard=-1, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"](_recv_save/Const_0, save/restore_slice_318/tensor_name, save/restore_slice_318/shape_and_slice)]]

Caused by op u'save/restore_slice_318', defined at:
File "/tmp/runner.py", line 35, in
load_model_to_session(session, model_dir, meta_file, ckpt_file)
File "/tmp/runner.py", line 6, in load_model_to_session
saver = tf.train.import_meta_graph(os.path.join(model_dir_exp, meta_file))
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/training/saver.py", line 1526, in import_meta_graph
**kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/meta_graph.py", line 502, in import_scoped_meta_graph
producer_op_list=producer_op_list)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/importer.py", line 285, in import_graph_def
op_def=op_def)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 2240, in create_op
original_op=self._default_original_op, op_def=op_def)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 1128, in init
self._traceback = _extract_stack()

DataLossError (see above for traceback): Unable to open table file /data/model/a.ckpt: Data loss: not an sstable (bad magic number): perhaps your file is in a different file format and you need to use a different restore operator?
[[Node: save/restore_slice_318 = RestoreSlice[dt=DT_FLOAT, preferred_shard=-1, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"](_recv_save/Const_0, save/restore_slice_318/tensor_name, save/restore_slice_318/shape_and_slice)]]
```

I wonder if there is any work-around for that.
I'm using tensorflow 0.12.1

Comment: There are two possibilites: (a) your input data was corrupted --- perhaps compare SHA hashes of the two files? or (b) there is something buggy in one of the builds of Tensorflow or the OS. It's hard to say which without more information.